# python dash table conditional formatting color scale

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want to color a column by value with color scale according to value high to small
like this

[image: https://i.imgur.com/GZpIXu1.png]

currently, I create the dash table in a function and send it by loop for each column;

```
def make_table_in_div(df, column_name):
    pv = pd.pivot_table(df, index=[column_name], values=['val1'], aggfunc=['mean', 'count']).reset_index()
    pv.columns = [column_name, 'val1', 'count']
    print(column_name)
    div = html.Div([html.H1(column_name), dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in pv.columns],
        data=pv.to_dict('records'),
    )], style={'height': 30, 'margin-right': 'auto', 'margin-left': 'auto', 'width': '800px'})  # 'width': '50%',
    return div

div = [make_table_in_div(df, column_name) for column_name in ['column_name']]
return div
```

the dash table looks as the flowing picture, and I want to colorize the value column
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. You should check out this link: https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting
specifically the part 'Highlighting with a colorscale on a single column'

I have written a quick example for you:

```py
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash_html_components as html
import colorlover
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

# Dash Application
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(
    [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    [0.328, 0.323, 0.193, 0.231, 0.216, 0.284, 0.250, 0.258, 0.394, 0.455],
    [67, 99, 109, 104, 88, 74, 32, 31, 33, 22]
)), columns=['column_name', 'value', 'count'])

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

# Function for styling table, defined below
cols = ['value']
(styles, legend) = discrete_background_color_bins(df, columns = cols)

app.layout = html.Div([
    legend,
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id = 'table',
        columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data = df.to_dict('records'),
        style_data_conditional = styles
    )
])

app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

[image]

This function returns the a list of styles for each row for the specified columns using the given colorscale.

To get the colorscale you need to install colorlover with `pip install colorlover`

Additional colorscales can be found here: https://github.com/plotly/colorlover

```py
# Function for styling the table
def discrete_background_color_bins(df, n_bins=7, columns='all'):

    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins+1)]
    if columns == 'all':
        if 'id' in df:
            df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number').drop(['id'], axis=1)
        else:
            df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number')
    else:
        df_numeric_columns = df[columns]
    df_max = df_numeric_columns.max().max()
    df_min = df_numeric_columns.min().min()
    ranges = [
        ((df_max - df_min) * i) + df_min
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    legend = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        backgroundColor = colorlover.scales[str(n_bins+4)]['div']['RdYlGn'][2:-2][i - 1]
        color = 'black'

        for column in df_numeric_columns:
            styles.append({
                'if': {
                    'filter_query': (
                        '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                        (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                    ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                    'column_id': column
                },
                'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                'color': color
            })
        legend.append(
            html.Div(style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '60px'}, children=[
                html.Div(
                    style={
                        'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                        'borderLeft': '1px rgb(50, 50, 50) solid',
                        'height': '10px'
                    }
                ),
                html.Small(round(min_bound, 2), style={'paddingLeft': '2px'})
            ])
        )

    return (styles, html.Div(legend, style={'padding': '5px 0 5px 0'}))
```

Comment: thanks.
A little bug when I use the function on multiple columns, I'll try to fix it.
Thanks for the answer!!!

https://i.imgur.com/bDrd8q1.png

Comment: Do you want to color the columns by using the same scale, or color them based on only the values in each column?

Comment: color them based on only the values in each column.
fixed that. again thank you :)
https://i.imgur.com/FxNLv42.png

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [The answer of Kristian Haga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63394947/9350669). - It's working great.

I'd like to summarize the options for future users with the same question and me. When we want to run it on multiple columns, there are two options:

1. The original function will colorize all the columns with same scale (min and max) so if I run with multiple columns (from the example: values and count) its returns the table style colorized based on the range of min and max out of all columns (from the example: 0.193,109).
   `discrete_background_color_bins(df, columns=['value','count'])`
   [image: https://i.imgur.com/bDrd8q1.png]

   ```
   def discrete_background_color_bins(df, n_bins=7, columns='all'):

    bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins+1)]
    if columns == 'all':
        if 'id' in df:
            df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number').drop(['id'], axis=1)
        else:
            df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number')
    else:
        df_numeric_columns = df[columns]
    df_max = df_numeric_columns.max().max()
    df_min = df_numeric_columns.min().min()
    ranges = [
        ((df_max - df_min) * i) + df_min
        for i in bounds
    ]
    styles = []
    legend = []
    for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
        min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
        max_bound = ranges[i]
        backgroundColor = colorlover.scales[str(n_bins+4)]['div']['RdYlGn'][2:-2][i - 1]
        color = 'black'

        for column in df_numeric_columns:
            styles.append({
                'if': {
                    'filter_query': (
                        '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                        (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                    ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                    'column_id': column
                },
                'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                'color': color
            })
        legend.append(
            html.Div(style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '60px'}, children=[
                html.Div(
                    style={
                        'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                        'borderLeft': '1px rgb(50, 50, 50) solid',
                        'height': '10px'
                    }
                ),
                html.Small(round(min_bound, 2), style={'paddingLeft': '2px'})
            ])
        )

    return (styles, html.Div(legend, style={'padding': '5px 0 5px 0'}))
   ```
2. If we want to colorize each column separately based on its min and max,
   [image]
   We will use the function below:
   (very similar but running on the columns first)

   ```
    def discrete_background_color_bins(df, n_bins=7, columns='all'):

        bounds = [i * (1.0 / n_bins) for i in range(n_bins+1)]
        if columns == 'all':
            if 'id' in df:
                df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number').drop(['id'], axis=1)
            else:
                df_numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes('number')
        else:
            df_numeric_columns = df[columns]
        df_max = df_numeric_columns.max().max()
        df_min = df_numeric_columns.min().min()
        ranges = [
            ((df_max - df_min) * i) + df_min
            for i in bounds
        ]
        styles = []
        legend = []
        for i in range(1, len(bounds)):
            min_bound = ranges[i - 1]
            max_bound = ranges[i]
            backgroundColor = colorlover.scales[str(n_bins+4)]['div']['RdYlGn'][2:-2][i - 1]
            color = 'black'

            for column in df_numeric_columns:
                styles.append({
                    'if': {
                        'filter_query': (
                            '{{{column}}} >= {min_bound}' +
                            (' && {{{column}}} < {max_bound}' if (i < len(bounds) - 1) else '')
                        ).format(column=column, min_bound=min_bound, max_bound=max_bound),
                        'column_id': column
                    },
                    'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                    'color': color
                })
            legend.append(
                html.Div(style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '60px'}, children=[
                    html.Div(
                        style={
                            'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                            'borderLeft': '1px rgb(50, 50, 50) solid',
                            'height': '10px'
                        }
                    ),
                    html.Small(round(min_bound, 2), style={'paddingLeft': '2px'})
                ])
            )

        return (styles, html.Div(legend, style={'padding': '5px 0 5px 0'}))
   ```